# How to insert element before another one?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get an element before another one. This:

```
var textP = document.createElement("p");
textP.innerHTML = text;

form.appendChild(textP);
```

Does this:

```
<p>Test</p>
<input type="text" name="test"></input>
```

But I want this:

```
<p>Test</p><input type="text" name="test"></input>
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Pretty sure that's the exact same thing?

Comment: No, I don't want the space between them.

Comment: No one is going to see that anyway unless they view the source. The rendered output is the same.

Comment: There is so much fail in this question

Comment: No I mean in the same line on the screen, you can see that the text is above the form.

Comment: @XLordalX then it's __not__ this `linefeed`'s fault.

Comment: If you want the paragraph and input next to each other on the screen, use CSS to set the paragraphs display to inline.

Comment: I'm sorry,  but this is stupid question. There's no diference.

Comment: This isn't a stupid question... it's a question that shows that he doesn't understand what happens to his HTML after its parsed.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry I've got the answer. I used <span>text</spawn> and now it works. I'm just a beginner.

Comment: the code indentation is not reflected in the browser rendering... also, if you want to follow some dev rules about structuring code, it is even better to have input bellow paragraph... and i do not know if that is a correct tag formatting for <input />

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo That isn't a duplicate at all.

Comment: @Brad sorry, I've hit the wrong question as a reference question. Now I can't fix it. I've retracted my vote.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP does not understand the basics of the difference between the DOM and layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your HTML has been parsed, it is no longer HTML... a Document is created from it, and that is what exists in your browser.  There is a sort of tree structure of **elements**, not a bunch of text with **tags**.

The reason this distinction matters is that you work with the DOM in JavaScript, not the HTML markup.  When you create an element, it creates it in the DOM.  It does not go back and manipulate the raw HTML and re-parse the whole document.  The original HTML never exists where JavaScript can get to it.

Now, your browser's developer tools will re-generate HTML representing the DOM, but this is not the original HTML.  If you make a syntax error in your HTML, you will see that it doesn't exist in the DOM.  The DOM shown to you is how the browser is representing your document, not HTML tags.